# Unable to connect to s3 buckets from pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-sdk

I am trying to connect to my s3 buckets using my Spark as follow:

```
rdd=sc.textFile("s3n://bucketname/objectname")
rdd=sc.textFile(""s3a://bucketname/objectname")
```

and changed my `cores-site.xml` as pers s3a or s3n but I am getting error as follow. Tried various changes in my hadoop `core-site.xml`. I am getting errors such as "load aws credentials from any provider in chain". {/.aws credentials file is there with right credentials}

> ResponseStatus: Bad Request, XML Error Message: `AuthorizationHeaderMalformed`The authorization header is malformed; a non-empty Access Key (AKID) must
>   be provided in the credential

```
   <configuration>
    <property>
      <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
      <value>hdfs://********.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>fs.s3a.impl</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
      <value>ACCESSKEYID</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
      <value>SECRETKEY</value>
    </property>
    </configuration>
```

I added aws-sdk-s3 into my spark jars file. Please provide me directions to get me on to the right track.

Complete error message:

```
Bad Request, XML Error Message: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>AuthorizationHeaderMalformed</Code><Message>The authorization header is malformed; a non-empty Access Key (AKID) must be provided in the credential.</Message><RequestId>E64EEB94923F0FF7</RequestId><HostId>cmAiSUGZo7w7IgK3gJ+ubuWdlXwffEhpnpdnkoJQ2hLP8EHBXZDau0mFCKCC3eWBtfL9V1Le4Mw=</HostId></Error>
```

Comment: you should be using `s3a` instead of `s3n` as you have mentioned the implementation is `S3AFileSystem` and the read should be `rdd=sc.textFile("s3a://bucketname/objectname")`

Comment: I am able to figure out that my buckets were in a different region and my awscli was configured to a different region. Resetting awscli settings resolved my issue.

Comment: don't bother with that fs.s3a.impl setting anyway; that's just a superstition which seems to propagate through blog posts. Just use the URL directly